# Не работает функция

Tags: jquery, функции

```
(function($){
$(window).load(function(){

var scrollSpeed = 30;
var current = 0;
var direction = 'h';

$('.rainbow_box').mousedown(function(){ return false; });
function bgscroll () {
    current -= 1;
    $('div.rainbow_cougar').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current+"px 0" : "0 " + current+"px");
}

setInterval("bgscroll()", scrollSpeed);

});
})(jQuery);
```

Жалуется на `bgscroll is not defined`, но функция раньше работала. Добавил только `$(window).load(function(){` . Почему такое может быть?

Comment: Вынесите функцию bgscroll за пределы $(window).load(function(){

Comment: @Kison, неверно, надо просто setInterval по человечески использовать а не с кавычкам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция точно находится там, где вы указали?

У меня всё ок:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scrollSpeed = 30;
    var current = 0;
    var direction = 'h';

    $('.rainbow_box').mousedown(function(){ 
        return false; 
    });

    function bgscroll () {
        current -= 1;
        $('div.rainbow_cougar').css("backgroundPosition", (direction == 'h') ? current+"px 0" : "0 " + current+"px");
    }
    setInterval(bgscroll, scrollSpeed);
});
```